# RecyclerView: How to simulate ListView's draw selector on top?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-recyclerview

I would like to create a `RecyclerView` that draws a selector on top of its items. It should be rendered on top of the items, that means I cannot simply set a `StateListDrawable` as item background.

I am particularly interested in the pressed state, i.e. something should be drawn if (and only if) an item is pressed.

`RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` is capable of drawing over items of a `RecyclerView`. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
public final class ItemPressedDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private final Rect rect = new Rect();

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        final int count = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
            final View child = parent.getChildAt(index);
            if (child.isPressed()) {
                drawOverlay(c, child);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawOverlay(Canvas c, View child) {
        c.save();
        rect.set(child.getLeft(), child.getTop(), child.getRight(), child.getBottom());
        c.clipRect(rect);
        c.drawColor(0x80ff0000);
        c.restore();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `RecyclerView` does not seem to redraw the item decoration if the drawable state of one of its children changes. So how do I get it to do that?

I have tried to add an `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` and call `recyclerView.invalidate()` from its `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method but that did not work.

Answer (score 8):

If you can use `FrameLayout` as root, and your selector is semi-transparent, below layout may useful.

`android:foreground`, not `android:background`

layout/view_listitem.xml

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:foreground="@drawable/your_selector">

  <!-- your list items -->

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution that seems to work. I had to subclass `RecyclerView` in order to invalidate the view and force the item decorations to be drawn again.

```
public class ChildDrawableStateRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    /* constructors omitted */

    @Override
    public void childDrawableStateChanged(View child) {
        super.childDrawableStateChanged(child);

        // force ItemDecorations to be drawn
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

I have no idea if this is the right way to do it. Please provide better answers if you have any.

I will also have to check if ripple effects can be implemented this way.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a completely different approach. Instead of implementing a `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` I wrote a `RelativeLayout` subclass that can draw a selector in the foreground. I use this layout as a container for all list items that need a selector on top.

This approach also seems to work well with ripple drawables.

```
public class SelectorRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    public static final int[] ATTRS_LIST_SELECTOR = { android.R.attr.listSelector };

    private final Drawable selector;

    public SelectorRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SelectorRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SelectorRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ATTRS_LIST_SELECTOR, 0, 0);
        selector = a.getDrawable(0);
        a.recycle();

        if (selector != null) {
            setWillNotDraw(false);
            selector.setCallback(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();

        final Drawable d = selector;
        if (d != null && d.isStateful()) {
            d.setState(getDrawableState());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void jumpDrawablesToCurrentState() {
        super.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();

        final Drawable d = selector;
        if (d != null) {
            d.jumpToCurrentState();
        }
    }

    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void drawableHotspotChanged(float x, float y) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            return;
        }

        super.drawableHotspotChanged(x, y);

        final Drawable d = selector;
        if (d != null) {
            d.setHotspot(x, y);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        final Drawable d = selector;
        if (d != null) {
            d.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            d.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean verifyDrawable(Drawable who) {
        return who == selector || super.verifyDrawable(who);
    }
}
```